# How can I insert an item in the middle of an object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, insert

If I have a stdClass object like the one below, which has three arrays with non-numeric keys, what's the best way to insert another item into the object between my-account and settings?

```
[menu1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [my-account] => Array
            (
                [title] => 'My Account'
                )
        [settings] => Array
            (
                [title] => 'Settings'
                )
        [payments] => Array
            (
                [title] => 'Payments'
                )
)
```

Comment: Why is the position of the element in the array important ?

Comment: I dont understand why you would want to add something in the middle - surely you reference them by key ?

Comment: Software using the object renders it in the order it exists in the object (for loop). PHP preserves positions of objects and arrays opposed to other languages like JS and PERL and some scripts depend on this order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no function to do this. You'll have to do your own and rebuild your object

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/fba96/3

```
<?php
function insert_after($var, $key, $value, $after){
    $new_object = array();
    foreach((array) $var as $k => $v){
       $new_object[$k] = $v;
       if ($after == $k){
           $new_object[$key] = $value;
       }
    }
    $new_object = (object) $new_object;
    return $new_object;
}

$var = insert_after($var, 'new dummy var between', array('title' => 'value'), 'my-account');
```

Comment: can you give an example of what that might look like

Answer (score 3):

Create your own class for this with functions to add and remove items and their attributes. Then use some functions such as @genesis provided.

Answer (score 2):

Add your item and then remove and re-add the items which ned to come after it:

```
$menu1->newitem = array('title'=>'Title');
$settings = $menu1->settings;

unset($menu1->settings);
$menu1->settings = $settings;
unset($settings);

unset($menu1->payments);
$menu1->payments = $payments;
unset($payments);
```